# Removing Plumbing From Bathroom Sink

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

I am trying to remove a bathroom sink and vanity (the entire set-up), and unfortunately for me, I just discovered that the hot/cold water lines as well as the drainage line (that connects to the home sewage line) was drilled up through the floor.

I have no issue getting into the crawlspace and cutting and capping the hot and cold cpvc piping for the water line, but what is the appropriate way to remove the larger piping that connects to the sewage line?

**EDIT**
Is this what you mean by a clean-out connecter?

[image]

Comment: Is the sewage line cast iron or PVC?

Comment: It's white PVC, just eyeballing it maybe 3 inch, connecting to the typical black (I assume) PVC in the crawlspace.

Comment: Is this a permanent removal or temporary until a new bathroom is installed?

Comment: @FreeMan - permanent removal

Answer (score 2):

Usually the same way.

Cut or unscrew enough pipe and place a cap on the end to prevent sewer gas from escaping.

Depending on type of pipe, should find the right connections to add a cap at most big box and plumbing stores.

Comment: is a sewage line not like a water line, in a sense that the second I breach the piping "sewage" will leak from the pipe?  Or am I safe to cut the pipe in the crawlspace and purchase a cap of sorts to glue? and cover with?

Comment: A sewage line isn't pressurized like a water line.  Unless something's wrong, like during a flood or a major blockage.  But normally, when not actively in use, the pipes should be mostly empty.    There may be some water left in the pipes so be prepared for some dirty water to come out when you cut it especially if it's overhead.

Comment: Unless it is blocked/backed up, most of the the stuff should be below/past.  There usually is a bit on the bottom of pipe that might leak out, but an old rag/small bucket/can should catch it.  Would not hurt to have the parts needed handy, before cutting/unscrewing.  Usually just a unpleasant smell.

Comment: The P-trap should be the only section that has the most water(a few cups) in it, at the bottom.

Comment: i actually just measured and at the top the cap is about 2 3/4 so i might actually need a 2 1/2 cap.  I'm going to head to my local box store and get a 2, 2 1/2 and 3 inch caps just so fingers crossed I'll have all options needed.  This will need to be glued onto the end also, just like the cpvc caps, correct?

Comment: @crip659 - what tool is best recommended to cut the PVC Pipe of this size?  Hacksaw?

Comment: Might get a clean-out connector, it should have a threaded section for a cap. the store should know, usually sizes go by pipe diameter, not width of ends.  A hacksaw will work, try to make a square cut.

Comment: @crip659 - see my edit - is that what you are referencing?  Glue the end on, then I simply screw the cap on the end?

Comment: That will work, might come in handy one day.

Comment: I might suggest, @StanleyJones, that you leave as much pipe as possible in case you or someone else ever decide that these lines are needed again. That way, there's room enough to attach new plumbing to the existing pipe one the caps are cut off. If you cut them too short, then reusing the lines in the future becomes much more difficult.